# How to eleminate duplicates with out using few transformations

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where I should eliminate the duplicates from source and load them to target. But I should not use the below

1) SQL Override

2) Lookup

3) Aggregator

4) Rank

5) Unix commands

6) Java

Note : The source has huge number of records

Please help me in this regard

Thanks and Regards

Raj

Comment: Weird requirement of not using the above transformations. Well, Did you try using `Distinct` in the `Source qualifier`

Comment: Ya that's true its a Weird requirement but I am doing a little bit research (as part of a task)

I am trying to achieve this using Stored Procedure transformation . Actually I am planning not to use any cache

Answer (score 1):

I assume the requirement in fact is to **remove duplicates without caching**. I see two solutions possible:

- push it down to source database by using 'Distinct' Source Qualifier property, or
- Sort the data using `Source Qualifier` property `Number Of Sorted Ports` (remember to put the ports in the correct order), create `Expression Transformation` that will use a local variable to compare current vs previous key and an output flag that indicates a duplicate for removal, followed by `Filter Transformation` that allows only non-duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you Maciejg I will try that